# check/get IIS values in .net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

**Need:** Trying to implement a javascript redirect for a timeout action, and need to know the interval to set the timeout. The redirect forces the user to re-login. I would like to get this value from IIS to match the timeout on there.

**Question:** Is it possible to retrieve IIS setting values using the .net mvc framework? How would I get the time-out value that resides under the ASP settings?

Comment: are you using Identity Membership?

Comment: either way, the expiration should be set, or you can add a cookie on login, and just use the javascript to check it's value without going back to the server

Comment: does that allow me to retrieve iis values? I'm not currently using it, and I only just now heard about it from you just now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the IIS session timeout value (in minutes) in an ASP.NET or ASP Classic application:

```
Session.Timeout
```

This value corresponds to the value you'll find when you select your website in IIS Manager and navigate to either:

**ASP.NET**

- ASP.NET --> Session State --> Cookie Settings --> Time-out (in minutes)

**ASP Classic**

- IIS -> ASP --> Session Properties --> Time-out

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve IIS values by using the [ServerManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx) class (Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll).
Like Jonesy said, you can then pass the timeout back to the browser via a cookie or other means.

To get the ASP.NET session timeout, I suggest you specify the timeout required in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
       mode="InProc"
       cookieless="true"
       timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then you can read the timeout using the following code:

```
 //if it is a root application, then the path will be "/"
 var configPath = "/YourApplicationName";

 var config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);

 // get the object related to the <sessionSate> section.
 var sessionSection = (System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection)config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");

 // get the session timeout value
 var timeOut= SessionSection.Timeout;
```

For reference see: [How to: Access ASP.NET Configuration Settings Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0.aspx)

The timeout can be stored as a static to be retrieved when needed.

You can also retrieve the setting from the current session (but I don't think that is what you require):
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout

Comment: Do you have an example of how to retrieve the time-out settings under ASP configuration?

Comment: There is Server.SiteDefaults.ConnectionTimeout, but I'm not sure that corresponds to the ASP time-out as that is 20 minutes and this is showing 2 minutes.

Comment: Ok, I see that you want to get the Session timeout. I will update my answer.